# footer layout not working

Tags: html, css

I use this Bootstrap for my page footer.
I want the `<div>` tag with class `col-sm-3 myCols` to show horizontal side by side (like 4 columns) and when the browser width less than "1136" there goes vertical like now. and the social icon show in a row above the copyright section.

```css
#myFooter {
 background-color: #373a48;
 color:white;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright{
 background-color: #383737;
 padding-top:3px;
 padding-bottom:3px;
 text-align: center;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright p{
 margin:10px;
 color: #ccc;
}

#myFooter ul{
 list-style-type: none;
    padding-left: 0;
    line-height: 1.7;

}

#myFooter h5{
 font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 30px;
}

#myFooter a{
 color:#d2d1d1;
 text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter a:hover, #myFooter a:focus{
 text-decoration: none;
 color:white;
}

#myFooter .myCols{
 text-align: center;
}

#myFooter .social-networks{
 text-align: center;
 padding-top: 30px;
 padding-bottom: 38px;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a{
    font-size: 32px;
    margin-right: 5px;
    margin-left: 5px;
    color: #f9f9f9;
    padding: 10px;
    transition: 0.2s;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a:hover{
 text-decoration: none;

}

#myFooter .facebook:hover{
 color:#0077e2;
}

#myFooter .google:hover{
 color:#ef1a1a;
}

#myFooter .twitter:hover{
 color: #00aced;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1136px){
 #myFooter {
  text-align: center;
 }
}
```

```html
<footer id="myFooter">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Get started</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>About us</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Company Information</a>                           </li>
                        <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Support</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Help desk</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
                <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
                    <h5>Legal</h5>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="social-networks">
            <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
            <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official">
            </i></a>
            <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
        </div>
        <div class="footer-copyright">
            <p>© 2016 Copyright Text </p>
        </div>
  </footer>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using a flexbox for `#myFooter` and the row

```css
#myFooter {
  background-color: #373a48;
  color: white;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
}

#myFooter .container {
  width: 100%;
}

#myFooter .row {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  width: 100%;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright {
  background-color: #383737;
  padding-top: 3px;
  padding-bottom: 3px;
  text-align: center;
  width: 100%;
}

#myFooter .footer-copyright p {
  margin: 10px;
  color: #ccc;
}

#myFooter ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding-left: 0;
  line-height: 1.7;
}

#myFooter h5 {
  font-size: 18px;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
  margin-top: 30px;
}

#myFooter a {
  color: #d2d1d1;
  text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter a:hover,
#myFooter a:focus {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: white;
}

#myFooter .myCols {
  text-align: center;
  width: 25%;
}

#myFooter .social-networks {
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30px;
  padding-bottom: 38px;
  width: 100%;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a {
  font-size: 32px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  margin-left: 5px;
  color: #f9f9f9;
  padding: 10px;
  transition: 0.2s;
}

#myFooter .social-networks a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
}

#myFooter .facebook:hover {
  color: #0077e2;
}

#myFooter .google:hover {
  color: #ef1a1a;
}

#myFooter .twitter:hover {
  color: #00aced;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1136px) {
  #myFooter {
    text-align: center;
  }
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />

<footer id="myFooter">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
        <h5>Get started</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Sign up</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Downloads</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
        <h5>About us</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Company Information</a> </li>
          <li><a href="#">Contact us</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Reviews</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
        <h5>Support</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">FAQ</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Help desk</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Forums</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-3 myCols">
        <h5>Legal</h5>
        <ul>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Service</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Terms of Use</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Privacy Policy</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="social-networks">
    <a href="#" class="twitter"><i class="fa fa-twitter"></i></a>
    <a href="#" class="facebook"><i class="fa fa-facebook-official">
            </i></a>
    <a href="#" class="google"><i class="fa fa-google-plus"></i></a>
  </div>
  <div class="footer-copyright">
    <p>© 2016 Copyright Text </p>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: and if i don't want to use bootstrap.min.css how can i made something exactly like this?

Comment: I removed bootstrap.min.css. added a width of 100% for .container and 25% for myCols. You may want to finetune the appearance of the text if you like.

Comment: sorry but i want change it back to vertical like before when max-width:1136px  :-(  what change do i need to do that in @media part?

Answer (score -1):

Use `<div class="container-fluid">` before `<div class="container">,` and close it at the bottom. try it.